# Can USGS High Resolution Orthoimagery be viewed online?

Tags: imagery, satellite, aerial-photography, usgs, viewer

I found the [USGS EarthExplorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov) where one can download their High Resolution Orthoimagery. This imagery can also be previewed in the EarthExplorer once a particular tile is found, but I wonder if there is a place online where the whole United States can be viewed at once (possibly the latest and highest resolution images).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Zoom Earth](https://zoom.earth/#38.89768,-77.036526,3z,sat,am,2017-03-05) which allows you to control dates and times. You could also access [Remote Pixels Satellite Search](https://remotepixel.ca/projects/satellitesearch.html). Finally, You can get to the raw data on [Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/public-datasets/landsat/) (Landsat Only)

Comment: Thanks for the links! I am bit confused now... I am looking for very detailed imagery that allows data tracing for OpenStreetMap (basically equals mostly to public domain or special permission). I found USGS has sometimes coverage with resolution of 0.075m/0.25ft per pixel, but those look like aerial images taken from a plane. Does Zoom Earth provide NASA (=public domain) imagery only? In the corner it says (c) Microsoft (Bing?). I could really use some satellite imagery guide probably.